# How can I display inspection errors in realtime in Project view of Intellij Idea?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

Spring related inspections of Intellij Idea are very useful for me. However, with Intellij Idea Ultimate 2018.3, when Spring related inspections run, they mark errors in various files but these files are not marked as having errors in the project view.

I would like these errors to be marked in the project view in the same way compile errors are marked. To be clear, build automatically is checked and compiler errors are marked in real time in project view.

Inspection profile settings define many errors and they are indeed marked on the right of relevant java files but there is nothing in the project view so I'm likely to miss these errors. One option is to run a bulk inspection but that is just an interruption of my development process. Inspections catch errors in real time, so why should not I find about these from the project view?

How do I configure idea so that errors from inspection results are marked in the project view?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Please enable File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Build project automatically, it should help.

Comment: Build automatically is checked/on. It does not work for inspections. It works for compiler errors as I've written in the question.